# Swapping Producton <> Staging Azure App Slots from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to simplify my workflow here.  Currently, what I do is:

1. Deploy to Staging (right-click > Publish) from VS
2. Smoketest
3. Swap Prod <> Staging from within the Azure portal

I'm trying to stay within VS here.  I know I can use Powershell to initiate a swap action - what's the sanest way to achieve this purely within Visual Studio?

Comment: what is the scope of your smoketest? Is it just to warm up the application?

Comment: @CtrlDot smoketest is irrelevant, I'm more concerned about replacing 3 with `from within VS`

Comment: ASE has "auto-swap" slots already.  So you could just enable that.  It does a "smoketest" to warm up the application, but nothing more.  That is why I was asking.

Comment: @CtrlDot - I'm aware of this.  I don't want auto-swap - I want to be able to swap from VS.

Comment: This is a feature that is not available. It is in the feedback portal with not much love. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170031-sdk-and-tools/suggestions/3083799-add-the-ability-to-swap-vips-from-within-visual-st

Answer (score 0):

@RobVious, 
According to your description, I recommend you can use the command '`Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot`' Please refer to [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harikharan/2015/01/01/swap-slots-in-azure-web-site-when-there-are-2-or-more-staging-slots-using-azure-powershell/).

Meanwhile, AFAIK,  we also can swap the staging and production via deployment on TFS using [powershell](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/deployment-slots-webapps).

Comment: Can I run this directly from VS?

Comment: For this method 'witch-AzureWebsiteSlot',  you need call it using powershell.